# jQuery Mobile menu nested list links

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Got a mobile site with a jquery mobile menu (nested-list). Every item in the list is a link to a new page. What If I want to go to www.AAAAAAAAAA.com , how is this possible? Do jQuery Mobile got a function that makes this possible?

In my situation and this example I have to navigate trough every levels (3 levels) before I get into a new site. It's not possible to get into every link.

What if the user only want to go to "www.AAAAAAAA.com" showed in the list.

This is hard to explain but one solution is to add the "clicked list element" to the level beneath to get it to work.

```
<ul> // level 1
 <li><a href='www.test1.com'>aaa</a></li>
  <ul> // level 2
     <li><a href='www.test.com'>aaa</a></li>
     <li><a href='www.AAAAAAAAA.com'>Exsample</a></li> <----PROBLEM
         <ul> //level 3
             <li><a href='www.test.com'>TEST</a></li>
             <li><a href='www.test1.com'>aaa</a></li>
             <li><a href='www.test2.com'>aaa</a></li>
             <li><a href='www.test3.com'>aaa</a></li>
```

Is there a way to insert what you have clicked into the new level and then set rel="external" on the element. Like when you've cliked on www.AAAAAAAA.com item it get's like this

```
    <li><a href='www.AAAAAAAAA.com'>Exsample</a></li> <----PROBLEM
         <ul> //level 3
             <li rel="external"><a href='www.AAAAAAAAA.com'>Exsample</a></li> <--inserted! 
             <li><a href='www.test.com'>TEST</a></li>
             <li><a href='www.test1.com'>aaa</a></li>
             <li><a href='www.test2.com'>aaa</a></li>
             <li><a href='www.test3.com'>aaa</a></li>
```

Comment: Side note: nested `<ul>`s go inside a `<li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried [split button lists](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-split.html)?

Not sure if this works with nested ULs, but I would give it a try. This would give you two buttons per list item, so one could be directly linking to www.AAAAAAAAAA.com, the other one would be for digging one level down.

Could be confusing though.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thanks :) .